# Django: How to change the css id of a ModelMultipleChoiceField in a form?

Tags: django, forms

One of my forms is using a ModelMultipleChoiceField and it's showing a list of checkboxes on the html.

```
class CreateProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=50)
    topics = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Assign Topic(s)', 
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        event = kwargs.pop('event')
        super (CreateProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['topics'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter(event=event)
```

HTML output

```
<div id="div_topics">
    <label class="fields">
        <strong><label for="id_topics_0">Assign Topic(s)</label></strong>
    </label>
    <ul>
<li><label for="id_topics_0"><div class="checker" id="uniform-id_topics_0"><span><input type="checkbox" name="topics" value="3" id="id_topics_0" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div> Size</label></li>
<li><label for="id_topics_1"><div class="checker" id="uniform-id_topics_1"><span><input type="checkbox" name="topics" value="2" id="id_topics_1" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div> Flavour</label></li>
<li><label for="id_topics_2"><div class="checker" id="uniform-id_topics_2"><span><input type="checkbox" name="topics" value="1" id="id_topics_2" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div> Citrus</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I change the value of the `id` of the `input type` element? Or basically change `id_topics_0` etc to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    event = kwargs.pop('event')
    super (CreateProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['topics'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter(event=event)
    self.fields['topics'].widget.attrs['class'] = "new_topics_class"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add auto_id option to form initial method. But it will change all ids for this form:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#configuring-html-label-tags